# Kernel log file flooded with chromium audit logs

Tags: kernel, chromium, logs

Running Ubuntu 20.04. Today my system suddenly restarted and taking a look at the /var/log/kern.log file I found the following right before the reset:

```
Jul 12 11:59:50 Emperor-Class kernel: [ 1406.986968] audit: type=1326 audit(1594544390.267:6907): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=3510 comm="chrome" exe="/snap/chromium/1213/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f57190ebb8f code=0x50000
Jul 12 11:59:51 Emperor-Class kernel: [ 1408.476494] audit: type=1326 audit(1594544391.759:6908): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=3510 comm="chrome" exe="/snap/chromium/1213/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f57190ebb8f code=0x50000
Jul 12 11:59:51 Emperor-Class kernel: [ 1408.477042] audit: type=1326 audit(1594544391.759:6909): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=3510 comm="chrome" exe="/snap/chromium/1213/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f57190ebb8f code=0x50000
Jul 12 11:59:52 Emperor-Class kernel: [ 1408.935620] audit: type=1326 audit(1594544392.215:6910): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=3510 comm="chrome" exe="/snap/chromium/1213/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f57190ebb8f code=0x50000
Jul 12 11:59:52 Emperor-Class kernel: [ 1408.936041] audit: type=1326 audit(1594544392.219:6911): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 pid=3510 comm="chrome:gdrv0" exe="/snap/chromium/1213/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7f57190ebb8f code=0x50000
     \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

The kern log is full of these kind of logs at > 1/second frequency that started on Jul 10. I believe there was an update mentioning chromium would only be available from snap on that date.

I don't know if this is related to the restart, I've been having lasting issues with restarts/freezes and upgrading to 20.04 is my latest attempt at getting rid of it, but the logs seem excessive. The log file is already 20 Mb in 2-3 days (older ones are ~1Mb) and at this rate it could reach upwards of 200 Mb/month. Is this normal? Is there a way to silence these logs and lighten the SSD usage?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug about this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1876442

However, there's no solution yet.

There's also a forum post with same problem: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444175

The proposed workaround is to "run the chromium app included in the snap package, but without the overheard from the snap":

`/snap/chromium/current/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome`

It seems to work. However, the Chromiun run using Snapo and the Chromium run directly don't share user settings, so any data (cookies, bookmarks, etc) are different. This can be an issue or a feature.